# appx parsing using PHP

Tags: php, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1, appxmanifest

I want to parse appx file using PHP
I read that appx is a type of zip archiveand can be opened through zip function in php

I want to take the AppxManifest.xml file from the appx file and read its contents

but ziparchive function is unable to open appx file in php

but same thing
when I renamed appx file to .zip in windows and then opened it

it showed all the contents